# Finding a transformation which minimizes absolute area under curve

Tags: optimization, area

I have a continuous everywhere differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$. It's absolute area from $x_0$ to $x_0+h$ can be calculated using $\displaystyle\int_{x_0}^{x_0+h}|f(x)|dx$ and I need to find a transformation(either linear or non-linear) that minimizes that area to 0, taking into account that there must exist a bijective between every point in the space before and after the transformation.

The question is very general so I don't even know where to start. Thanks in advance.

I need to find a transformation **to space** that minimizes such area, and preserves bijection between the points before and after the transformation.

Comment: It's quite unclear what you're asking. What do you want to transform? The function $f$? The domain of integration? What do you mean by "minimize the area to $0$"?

Comment: I want to transform the space in a way that the area under the curve between those points equals 0.

Comment: this injective transformation doesnt exists if $h$ varies continuously.

Comment: But the integral is invariant under transformation of the domain - if you let, say, $x=g(u)$ then the integral becomes $$\int_{u_{0}}^{u_{0}+k} |f(g(u))| |g'(u)| du$$ which has the same value. Unless you mean something else?

Comment: @Daniel: But the area under the transformed curve $f(g(u))$ is only $\int f(g(u))\,\mathrm du$, without the factor $|g'(u)|$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments suggest that, given $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$, you are looking for a continuously differentiable, invertible $g:[c,d] \to [a,b]$ which minimizes the integral $$\int_{c}^{d}|f(g(u))|du$$
It is impossible to make this equal to $0$, because $|f(g(u))| \ge 0$, and $f \circ g$ is continuous, so $\int_{c}^{d} |f(g(u))|du = 0 \implies f(g(u))=0$ for all $u \in [c,d]$ (if you are not familiar with this fact, try to prove it - it is a good exercise).

On the other hand, by choosing $g$ in a particular way, we can make the integral as small as we like. It is a standard fact that if $g$ is a continuously differentiable bijection, then its inverse $h$ is also continuously differentiable, and the derivative is given by $h'(g(x))=\frac{1}{g'(x)}$.

It follows that 
$$\int_{c}^{d} |f(g(u))|du = \int_{a}^{b}\frac{|f(x)|}{|g'(g^{-1}(x))|}dx$$
In particular, by choosing $g$ to be a linear function with a very steep gradient (correspondingly the interval $[c,d]$ will be very wide), the 'transformed area' can be made as small as you like.

This should make clear the non-naturality of the question you're asking. If you imagine estimating the area under the curve with rectangles - you've transformed the size of the space you're integrating over, and not taken into account the fact that the shape of the rectangles you're measuring with has changed. Therefore the integral is sensitive to 'how fast' you move through the interval $[a,b]$.